# QField Sync Install plugin error

Tags: qgis, installation, qfield

I tried to install QField Sync plugin on QGIS (I use version 3.18 italian on WIN 7), but I get this error...

```
Impossibile caricare il plugin 'qfieldsync' a causa di un errore chiamando il metodo classFactory() 

ImportError: cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'typing' (C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib\typing.py) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\__init__.py", line 40, in classFactory
    from qfieldsync.qfield_sync import QFieldSync
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\qfield_sync.py", line 33, in 
    from qfieldsync.core.cloud_api import CloudNetworkAccessManager
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\core\cloud_api.py", line 49, in 
    from qfieldsync.utils.qt_utils import strip_html
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\utils\qt_utils.py", line 31, in 
    from .file_utils import DirectoryTreeDict, DirectoryTreeType
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\utils\file_utils.py", line 23, in 
    from typing import List, TypedDict, Union
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'typing' (C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib\typing.py)

Versione Python: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] 
Versione di QGIS: 3.18.3-Zürich Zürich, 735cc85be9 

Percorso Python:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.18/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
```

Can you give me some information to solve?

Comment: You are using an old version of QGIS with Python 3.7. `TypedDict` was [introduced in Python 3.8](https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/10/python-type-hints-how-to-use-typeddict/#:~:text=TypedDict%20was%20specified%20in%20PEP,install%20it%20from%20typing%2Dextensions.). Therefore, the import line in the plugin fails and causes the error. You should update to a recent, supported version of QGIS. Otherwise, you would need to manually install [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) into your QGIS Python 3.7 installation e.g. via the OSGeo4W Shell on Windows or terminal in Linux.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem, I'm going through the same need

Comment: @BenW Please put answers in the space provided rather than as comments